# That dash in the command `-rm` in the makefile means something?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Today I saw something strange in a makefile.

Is that `-` in `-rm` a typo, or it means something?

```
appname = hello
obj = hello.o
gcc = gcc
cflags = -g -Wall

$(appname):$(obj)
    $(gcc) $(cflags) $(obj) -o $(app) -lpthread

# p_test.o:p_test.c
#   $(gcc) $(cflags) -c  hello.c

.PHONY:clean
clean:
    -rm $(obj)

.PHONY:run
run:
    ./hello 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It means to ignore errors, see [the fine manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html).

Therefore, your `make` will not fail if `$(obj)` doesn't exist by the time you issue `make clean`.